# Go言語でgoroutineを利用したstructの要素更新

Tags: go

go言語の並列処理（並行処理?）を利用して遅延更新のようなことは可能でしょうか？当方goroutine初心者です。

やりたいことは以下です

- ある関数の中でSampleObjectという構造体を返す

  - SampleObjectの中身は後の処理で確定するのでそれまで設定しない
  - SampleObjectを作った関数とは全然別の関数、スコープで中身を更新する

擬似コード的に書いてますので間違いあればご指摘ください。

```
// SampleObject内に受信用のchannelを設定して関数の外でSampleObjectの中身を更新する
func UpdateStructLater() SampleObject {
    return &SampleObject{make(chan, string)}
}

sObj := UpdateStructLater()
someSuperProcedure()
// sObj == "Hello" みたいな
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

channel そのものと、channel に送信された値とを区別してください。構造体のフィールドに channel を代入しても、その channel に送信された値がそのフィールドへ代入されるわけではありません。

初期化された構造体の一部を更新したい場合、並列処理は関係なく単にそのフィールドへ後から代入すれば良いです。Go では struct の初期化時に省略されたフィールドはゼロ値で初期化されることに注意してください。

```
sObj := SampleObject{}

update(&sObj)
// または
// sObj.SampleField = newValue()
// または *SampleObject のメソッドとして定義して
// sObj.update()
```

複数の更新をしなければならず、またそれらを並列的に処理して意味があるのであれば、たとえば sync パッケージを使って並列的に処理する方法が考えられます。下のコードでは Mutex を使って排他処理させつつ、WaitGroup を使って全ての更新が終わったことを検知しています。

この処理と同様のことは channel だけでも表現できますが、sync パッケージを使った方が見やすいかなと個人的には感じます。また、下のコードでは簡単のために Mutex のロック範囲を struct 全体にしていますが、フィールドごとにしても良いですし、依存関係が無いならロックしなくても平気です。

```
type SampleObject struct {
    X int
    Y int
    m sync.RWMutex
}

// 引数はポインタであることに注意
func update1(wg *sync.WaitGroup, sObj *SampleObject) {
    defer wg.Done()

    // 重い処理

    sObj.m.Lock()
    sObj.X = 42
    sObj.m.Unlock()
}

func update2(wg *sync.WaitGroup, sObj *SampleObject) {
    defer wg.Done()

    // 重い処理

    sObj.m.Lock()
    sObj.Y = 43
    sObj.m.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    sObj := SampleObject{}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // 各々の更新が終わったことを確認する用

    wg.Add(1)
    go update1(&wg, &sObj)
    wg.Add(1)
    go update2(&wg, &sObj)

    wg.Wait() // 全ての更新が終了するまで待つ

    // ...その後の処理...
}
```